# How can I get a vector output?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Following is The question which I am trying to solve. I have to return `Vector` as output but it is returning `Vector` address. I am unable to find out what I did wrong in the code.

Given a string, return a vector of Integer consisting of all the distinct numbers in the para. The numbers in the string are separated by space. If para is `“88 99 22 33 44 55 88 22 55 100″`, the output vector consists of the numbers – `88,99,22,33,44,55,100`

```
public class Numbers {

    public String num;

    public Numbers(String splitArray){
        this.num=splitArray;
    } 
}


import java.util.Vector;

public class DistinctNumbersInStrings {

    public static Numbers[] distinctNumbersInStrings(String str) {
        String[] splitArray = str.split(" ");
        Numbers[] number = new Numbers[splitArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
            number[i] = new Numbers(splitArray[i]);
        }
        return number;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numbers[] number = distinctNumbersInStrings("99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11");
        Vector v= new Vector(10);
        v.addElement(number);
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Vector` in 2014? Unless you use an API which still requires the use of `Vector`, don't use it!

Comment: Sry but I have to use this only.

Comment: You're printing a `Vector`. That's what you get from it's `toString()` method. If that's not what you want, you'd need to ... do something different.

Comment: Don't know if you realize you are trying to add a Numbers[] to a vector which has a **single** Number[] element. Is this what you want? Or do you want to add 9 numbers individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding `Numbers` as an element of the vector. I think you want to add all the numbers to it:

```
Vector v= new Vector(10);

for (Numbers n : numbers) {
    v.addElement(n);
}
System.out.println(v);
```

By the way, If I were you, I would change you class name `Numbers` to `Number` as it represents only one number. Something like:

```
public class Number {

    private String number;

    public Number(String number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in that way.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        Numbers[] number = distinctNumbersInStrings("99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11");
        Vector v= new Vector(10);
        v.addElement(number);
        displayAllNumbers(number);
    }

    private static void displayAllNumbers(Numbers[] number) {
        for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++)
        {
            if(i!=number.length-1)
            System.out.print(number[i].num + ",");
            else
                System.out.print(number[i].num);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Or do it in that way.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Numbers[] number = distinctNumbersInStrings("99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11");
        Vector<Numbers> v= new Vector<Numbers>(10);
        for(Numbers n : number)
        {
            v.add(n);
        }
        for(Numbers n : v){
            System.out.print(n.num);
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: Thansk for kind words. If I helped you please accept that answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is what you want? I will have only one entry in your `Vector` instead of one entry for each unique number.

Answer (score 0):

Modified my post.
This will work as well.

```
public class DistinctNumbersInStrings {
    public static Numbers[] distinctNumbersInStrings(String str){
        String[] splitArray = str.split(" ");
        Numbers[] number = new Numbers[splitArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++){
            number[i] = new Numbers(splitArray[i]);
        }
        return number;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Numbers[] number = distinctNumbersInStrings("99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11");
        Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
        for(Numbers n : number){
            v.addElement(n.num);
        }
        System.out.print(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrianRoach `vtoString()` returns a string!

Comment: @AlvinBunk When you pass an object to `println()` that's **exactly what happens**; the object's `toString()` method gets called.

Comment: Added some changes for the Vector. You should always define the type for the Vector, and there is no need to specify the number of elements since the Vector will grow. At the end you just print out the Vector.